# Silverlight (w/ SQL database) desktop application example?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, deployment

Are there any freeware/shareware examples of Silverlight desktop applications with a local SQL backend? 
I am planning to write a freeware/shareware personal finance application and I'm thinking if whether to do it on Silverlight or WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan on having the SQL backend, you should go with WPF.

Silverlight is restricted in what it can access on the filesystem, even if you run it in the trusted mode and sign the app properly.

People have been implementing all kinds of "good enough" databases that use Isolated Storage. You might use them depending on your level of comfort with the non-mainstream storage engine.

Are you sure you'd need a local SQL database? How much data are we talking about and what is the frequency of inserts/complexity of selects?

Answer (score 0):

For data storage you can use SQL CE4 or even a file based db like SQLite.
As rawpower said, I would recommand WPF, too.

Comment: I think you should be more precise in recommending SQL CE4 (which btw isn't even out yet, it's still a CTP) and SQLite - both are valid options *only* for WPF, but *not* for Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

There is SQLLite port for Silverlight and Sterling object-oriented database with LINQ support (much better for offline storage).

Both use IsolatedStorage, so no bloat WPF is needed.

Ideal for OOB Silverlight applications.